# Some websites load only text parts

Tags: router, internet, website

I'm having a problem loading some websites like Pintrest and Twitter when connected to through my router, either wired or wireless.  Only textual parts of the sites loads.

If I connect to Internet directly (without the router) everything loads fine.

Things I have tried:

- Changed router (Netgear N150 to TP-Link TD W8968).
- Checked on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE (I dont have any addons).
- Checked on different computers.

How can I fix things so browsers can load all of the resources they need to display a page properly?

Comment: yes only text is getting loaded. if i connect to internet without router. it is getting loaded normally. with router connected java script and css doesnt get loaded.

Comment: Also, what kind of internet connection do you have? Are you using Wi-Fi?

Comment: http://imgur.com/qkLzKyr

Comment: i had a tplink td-w8968 and netgear n150 routers and i faced the same problem on both the routers. i tried connecting by wired and wireless and in both cases i am facing the same problem

Comment: yes i faced problems with pintrest,twitter,wordpress.org,firefox addons page

Comment: Was it only on HTTPS pages? Check if your routers block port 443 (over which HTTPS/TLS works).

Comment: `when connected to router either wired or wireless I had the same problem. If I connect to internet directly`. So, is connecting to the router over a wired connection not connected directly?

Comment: Not particularly with HTTPS pages as i am able to load facebook google services normally

Comment: @DaveRook sorry i mean to say if i plug in the internet cable directly into my laptop lan port without any router in between.

Comment: Try hard setting your PC's networking to use a different DNS server; say Google's (8.8.8.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Internet connection require PPPoE? The PPPoE protocol has 8 bytes of overhead per packet, reducing your MTU from 1500 to 1492. PPPoE or not, some ISPs' networks have other MTU restrictions.

Client devices try to handle MTU restrictions by doing a procedure called "Path MTU Discovery" (PMTUD). But routers that misbehave and don't send ICMP "Fragmentation required but 'Don't Fragment' bit set" messages when necessary, and firewalls that block some kinds of ICMP messages, can cause PMTUD to break. Some <s>idiot</s>misinformed firewall administrators block all ICMP because they want to block ping attempts, but don't realize that ICMP is used for a lot more stuff than just ping, and that blocking ICMP does serious damage to the way some low-level parts of TCP/IP are supposed to work.

Good quality home gateways try to handle MTU restrictions by doing something called "TCP MSS Clamping", but it's possible that the gateways you've tried aren't doing it, or aren't doing a good job of it.

If your path to the Internet has an MTU restriction and it's not being handled properly, it can cause a situation where files smaller than the restricted MTU (say, an HTML file that's less than 1400 bytes) can fit in one packet that's not too big for the network, and get through. But files that are larger than that are put into full 1500 byte packets that are too large for the network and have to be dropped.

To get around this, Google's sites always negotiate a 1380-byte MSS for all TCP connections.

**Try this:**
To see if unhandled MTU restrictions are your problem, set the MTU fairly low (say 1300) on one of your machines that sees the problems. If a 1300 byte MTU solves your problem, try different settings closer and closer to 1500 to see where the cutoff is. Then set the largest working MTU on all your client machines.

If unhandled MTU restrictions end up being your problem, buy a better home gateway that does TCP MSS Clamping correctly (I know Apple's AirPort & Time Capsule lines have always done this well, but I can't vouch for others), and make sure you don't filter out ICMP, so that PMTUD can work.